# System will not boot after upgrade

Tags: boot, memory

I have a Supermicro X8DT3-F based system with 2 Xeon processors. I have 24 GB of system RAM and I preformed a upgrade to 48GB today. The system was not seeing the new RAM so I preformed a CMOS reset. After the CMOS reset the system saw all the RAM but now Windows will not boot. Attempting to boot into Safe Mode results in the system reseting itself at the login prompt. Attempting to boot normally leads to a "black screen of death" where the log-in screen would normally be. If I attempt to load from a DVD recovery disk the system never loads into recovery mode. What gives?

the system is running Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: If you remove the extra RAM, will it boot then into some mode? Is the new 24GB of RAM the same make and model (same specs / voltages / timings) as the old RAM?
Also, just as a sidenote, when you reset the CMOS, did you perhaps lose some settings (RAM settings/voltages/speeds etc, AHCI/RAID settings which Windows does not like)

Comment: Problem solved. I reset the CMOS a second time using failsafe settings and the system started working normally. The first reset must have changed some setting the windows did not much care for

Comment: I see, yes the failsafe settings usually are a bit more loose on the memory timings and such (which may be an issue in case there is a difference between the RAM modules). Gla to hear that the problem was solved!